# Setting AVAudioSession Output Only

Tags: audio, port, avaudiosession

I've been looking for a while online and have yet to find an answer to this question.  I am looking to stream audio from a bluetooth microphone through the earbuds of the iPhone.  I have been able to configure streaming from the microphone and streaming to the earbuds separately, but not simultaneously. I've done this by configuring the AudioSession to do such:

```
// Set up Audio Session

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error in Setting Audio Session Category");
    error = nil;
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error in Setting Audio Session Active");
    error = nil;

    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *mDes in audioSession.availableInputs){
        printf("Port: %s\n",[mDes.portType UTF8String]);
        if ([mDes.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP]) {
            [audioSession setPreferredInput:mDes error:&error];
            if (error != nil)
                printf("Error Setting Preferred Input\n");
            else
                printf("Success\n");
            error = nil;
        }
    }
```

It seems that when I set the preferred input, it also sets the output. I've tried overriding the output after the fact, but that resets the input.  Is there a way to configure the Audio Session's inputs and outputs separately?

Thanks.

Comment: I spoke with Apple about this and setting the Audio Session Category to MultiRoute could allow for audio to be routed separately.  Unfortunately, Bluetooth devices are not enabled for this Category, so according to Apple, this is not possible with iOS 7.

Comment: is this done after set avcapturesession or before? thanks